# Python 2.7 MSSQL Incorrect Syntax near Order

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pymssql

I have searched high and low to look for the solution to this problem, I am receiving the error when I add the Order by to the statement:

> (156, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

The code in my  .py file is:

```
db = pymssql.connect(server='DESKTOP-3G1FB9B\SQLEXPRESS', user='sa', password='', database='Osmium')
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM delayed Order by ID ASC)"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

If I remove the 'Order by ID ASC' it executes fine, but I need to order the results and am unable to find a solution. Entering the query into SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and adding "Osmium.dbo.delayed" it returns the correct result, I just need it to work within the Python (2.7) script

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Osmium.dbo.delayed Order by ID ASC
```

Comment: Everything looks fine here. However, just a wild guess - try wrapping things with `[]`: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [delayed] Order by [ID] ASC`

Comment: Try it without having the statement wrapped in parentheses: `sql = "SELECT ...`

Comment: Brilliant, I have put the wrapped them in the [ ] but that sadly didn't solve it but removing the parentheses instantly solved the problem thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting this to make an answer, and explain why:

Change your `sql` variable declaration to be:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [delayed] ORDER BY [ID] ASC"
```

*ORDER BY* is a clause in T-SQL, and therefore doesn't need parentheses to establish any order of operations. The square brackets can be used to surround certain objects in SQL Server to allow for use of reserved words (for example, if you have a column named something like [file]) or certain characters like a hyphen (a database named [your-db]).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. when I granted the update permission.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).